# How to combine a SELECT query and a COUNT(*) query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
          c.cd,
          c.c_id 
FROM
          f f 
          INNER JOIN s s 
                    ON s.s_id = f.s_id 
          INNER JOIN c c 
                    ON c.c_id = s.c_id 
WHERE f.m_id = 2 
          AND f.deleted = 'no' 
GROUP BY s.c_id 
ORDER BY f.update_datetime DESC ;
```

Which returns a sample result set:

```
c.cd    c.c_id
moot    4
derp    5
```

I have another query based on the `c.c_id` of the above result set which iterates for each record in the above result set:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totals FROM s
WHERE c_id =?
AND status='good';
```

returns `7` when `c_id=4` and returns `20` when `c_id=5`

Is there any way I can combine the two queries to form a result set like this?

```
c.cd    c.c_id  totals
moot    4       7
derp    5       20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
          c.cd,
          c.c_id,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  s WHERE c_id = c.c_id AND STATUS = 'good') totals 
FROM
          f INNER JOIN s  ON s.s_id = f.s_id 
          INNER JOIN c c ON c.c_id = s.c_id 
WHERE     f.m_id = 2 AND f.deleted = 'no' 
GROUP BY  s.c_id 
ORDER BY  f.update_datetime DESC ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT c.cd, c.c_id
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.status = 'good' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totals
  FROM f f
  INNER JOIN s s ON s.s_id = f.s_id 
  INNER JOIN c c ON c.c_id = s.c_id

WHERE f.m_id =2
  AND f.deleted='no'

GROUP BY s.c_id
ORDER BY f.update_datetime DESC;
```